# Friction on a system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

A plank of mass $m_1$ with a bar of mass $m_2$ placed on it lies on
a smooth horizontal plane. A horizontal force growing with time $t$
as $F = at$ ($a$ is constant) is applied to the bar. Find how the accelerations of the plank $w_1$ and of the bar $w_2$depend on $t$, if the coefficient
of friction between the plank and the bar is equal to $k$.
I don’t understand why til the static friction reaches its limiting value, the two bodies have the same acceleration (constant acceleration), and when I searched for its solution, I also found that he drew the two friction forces in the opposite direction in the free body diagram.

Comment: can the moderators tell how is the question a homework , and if it is so because it is  just tagged with homework then you have closed it wrong because the OP is new and he found a tag available and used it.  So why closing??